# How to disable the "Dashboard" and "Carousel" default tooltip for the xe:dashboard and xe:carousel controls?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to disable the "Dashboard" and "Carousel" tooltips that are displayed automatically when hovering over the the xe:dashboard and xe:carousel controls.

[image]

I did try adding the following scriptBolck but am still getting the tooltips

```
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[// disable tooltips
           $(document).ready(function(){
              console.log("IN $(document).ready(function(){ ");
              $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip()          // Init tooltips
              $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('disable') // Disable tooltips
              $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('enable')  // (Re-)enable tooltips
              $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('destroy') // Hide and destroy tooltips
       });]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a tooltip but a `title` property on the containing div with the xspDashboard class:

```
<div id="view:_id1:layout:contentPanel:dashboardPanel:mainDashboard" class="row xspDashboard" style="background-color: #eeeeee;border-radius: 8px;" title="Dashboard" role="presentation"><div class="xspDashboardInner">
```

The title is set in [DashboardRenderer.java line 163](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/61c7c0ccfc6e6871de8520d03b8b6dc41324c75f/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap/src/com/ibm/xsp/theme/bootstrap/renderkit/html/extlib/containers/DashboardRenderer.java#L163). I tried to set another title using the title property on xe:dashboard but this does not change the attribute but instead prints out the title text directly as you can see in line 161 of the source code. I believe that this is a bug as the renderer uses w.writeText(boardTitle, null); instead of w.writeAttribute("title", boardTitle, null);.

As a workaround you can clear the title like this:

```
$('.xspDashboard').attr("title", "")
```

Comment: Thanks Per, that works for me, and the following for the Carousel title

$('.xspCarousel').attr("title", "");